# Using react-native image picker requires 2 permissions- 1 is camera. And Google playstore requires a privacy statement for using camera

Tags: react-native, google-play, react-native-image-picker

I use RN-ImagePicker library. But, i use it only for picking images from external storage. But, this library doesn't work without both the permissions. 1 is camera and other one is storage. Google play console wont let me upload the apk. Saying, camera permission needs privacy policy.I am just doing an alpha release and don't really have a privacy statement. Is there a work around for this? Any help is appreciated.

- Removed camera permission and the image picker library wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: commented some code related to camera permissions in the image-picker library. And it works fine.